# How to convert list of loss tensor to numpy array

Tags: python, pytorch

Hi my loss is a list of tensors as follows:
`[tensor(0.0153, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>), tensor(0.0020, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)]`
how do I convert this to a NumPy array?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Tensor` contains more information than just its value, such as information about its gradient for back propagation. The tensor's `item` attribute isolates its value. Suppose `loss` is our list of losses, to get it as a numpy array, we can do the following:

```
losses_np = np.array([x.item() for x in losses])
```

For similar problems, the tensor's `values` and `numpy` attributes might also be useful.